# How to hide and show text on tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to make tab buttons.And put text on tab as heading.If i click on tabs then heading on tab should change with tab content.Now in my code if i click on first tab heading appear but if i click on second tab then first tab's heading not hide and second tab's heading appear.But i want 1st heading hide on second tab click.Help me!!

```
<script>
    function yess1(){
    document.getElementById("h1").style.display = "inline";
    }
     function yess2(){
      document.getElementById("h2").style.display = "inline";
     }
  </script>

  <style>
    #h1{
      display:none;
    }
    #h2{
      display:none;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="container">
  <h3 id="h1">All Students</h3>
  <h3 id="h2" >All Teachers</h3>


  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a onclick="yess1();" data-toggle="tab"     href="#one">Student</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="yess2();" data-toggle="tab" href="#two">Teacher</a></li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <p id="one" class="tab-pane fade in active">This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.    </p>
    <p id="two" class="tab-pane fade in active">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam efficitur ut risus id egestas. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam posuere sapien et sapien aliquam.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your Javascript:

```
<script>
    function yess1(){
        document.getElementById("h2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("h1").style.display = "inline";
        }
         function yess2(){
          document.getElementById("h1").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("h2").style.display = "inline";
         }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add explanation. You are answering for readers and not OP

Comment: Thanks Vengatesh rkv for help me

Comment: Thanks for your Comments

Answer (score 1):

As in your function your are showing the next div, but not hiding the previous one. You have to hide first and show second.

Please use the below code  -

```
function yess1(){
  document.getElementById("h1").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("h2").style.display = "none"; //Hiding Second 
}
function yess2(){
  document.getElementById("h2").style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById("h1").style.display = "none"; //Hiding first
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your functions -

JAVASCRIPT -

```
function yess1(){
    document.getElementById("h2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("h1").style.display = "inline";
  }
  function yess2(){
    document.getElementById("h1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("h2").style.display = "inline";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following approach:

#### Idea

- On click of `<a>`, hide all `.tab-pane` and `h3`.
- Then based on current element, show only elements that needs to be shown.

**Sample**

```js
function registerTabEvents(){
  var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  for(var i = 0; i< tabs.length; i++){
    tabs[i].addEventListener("click", toggleTab)
  }
}

function toggleTab(e){
  var tab = e.target.getAttribute('href').replace(/[^\w]/g, '');
  
  // Hide all elements
  hideAllElements('.tab-pane');
  hideAllElements('h3');
  
  // Show element to show
  document.querySelector("#" + tab).style.display = "inline-block";
  document.querySelector("#h_" + tab).style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hideAllElements(selector){
  var tabs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  for(var i = 0; i< tabs.length; i++){
    tabs[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

function initializeUI(){
  hideAllElements('.tab-pane');
  hideAllElements('h3');
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  registerTabEvents();
  initializeUI()
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 id="h_one">All Students</h3>
  <h3 id="h_two">All Teachers</h3>


  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a class="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#one">Student</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#two">Teacher</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <p id="one" class="tab-pane fade in active">This example shows how to create a basic navigation tab. It is not toggleable/dynamic yet (you can't click on the links to display different content)- see the last example in the Bootstrap Tabs and Pills Tutorial to find out how this can be done.</p>
    <p id="two" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam efficitur ut risus id egestas. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam posuere sapien et sapien aliquam.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Pointers

- Its better to avoid adding handlers in `HTML`. Using `.addEventListener` will allow you to make you code more modular. `.addEventListener` also binds `this` to current element and provides you with an `event` parameter.
- Instead of `yess1` and `yess2`, create a generic method that takes 1 argument and makes necessary changes.
- This is my personal POV, but its better to have an `initializeUI` function to determine the initial state.
- Since you are already using `bootstrap`, use class `.hide` instead of `style.display`.